# Is there any Open Sourced Android Apps public their crash reports?

Tags: android, crash, google-play, stack-trace

In the Google Play Developers Console, developers can see the crash reports of their App collected from end users. Is there any Apps public their crash reports?

I want to have an investigation of Android crashes, to see if there are some genera reasons. (in a large scale, thus I need crash reports from many Apps)

I am wondering is there any Open Source Android project which public their crash reports?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but it depends on the developer weather he has used these kind of android libs to detect crashes.
For example 
you are using some application it gets crashed.
you see a popup to submit that crash you send email.
in that email you can see that crash otherwise there are no such apps available as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I think my original question was also not well presented, which may cause some misunderstanding. I edited my question, too  !